CSS Vertical Clipping Issues in Responsive Safari for Multi-Column Layout
Seems to be a specific Safari glitch, but at particular narrow screen-sizes (i.e. iPhone) a multi-column layout (in my case a column: 2) on a parent nav item clips a "last-line" child button element midway through a word, vertically. Screenshot with red circles of the issue below:

This issue does not happen in Chrome/Edge nor Firefox at any size. Does anyone have any advice on a fix? Safari doesn't seem to support any of the CSS Fragmentation specs, and box-decoration-break has no effect on parent nav or child button.
